# google maps v3 open infowindow on click of external html link

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Wonder if anyone can help me, I have setup a google map all works nicely. The only thing I cant work out how to do is to open an info window based on ID from an external html link that's not in the JS.

```js
function initialize() {
// Create the map 
// No need to specify zoom and center as we fit the map further down.
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
// Custom markers
var icon = "img/marker.png";

// Define the list of markers.
// This could be generated server-side with a script creating the array.
var markers = [
    { val:0, lat: -40.149049, lng: 172.033095, title: "Title", html: "<div style='text-align:left'><h4 style='color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;'>Title</h4><strong>Telephone</strong><br /><br />Address</div>" },
    { val:1, lat: -41.185765, lng: 174.827516, title: "Title", html: "<div style='text-align:left'><h4 style='color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;'>Title</h4><strong>Telephone</strong><br /><br />Address</div>" },
];
// Create the markers ad infowindows.
for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);
function addMarker(data) {
  // Create the marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        icon: icon,
        id: data.val
    });

    // Create the infowindow with two DIV placeholders
    // One for a text string, the other for the StreetView panorama.
    var content = document.createElement("DIV");
    var title = document.createElement("DIV");
    title.innerHTML = data.html;
    content.appendChild(title);
    // Open the infowindow on marker click
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        map.setCenter(this.position);
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}

// Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
// This logic could be conbined with the marker creation.
// Just keeping it separate for code clarity.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (index in markers) {
    var data = markers[index];
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

<p id="1">link to open marker</p>
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Richard :)

Comment: What do you mean by "based on ID from an external html link that's not in the JS"?  That ID has to reference a marker somehow.  Is it a property of the marker?  The simplest way to open the existing infowindow on a marker is to trigger a "click" event on it, but you need some way to reference the marker.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="javascript:show(7)">The Golden Goose</a>
```

Then in your js have a function to open the infowindow (such as show()) which takes the properties from that link (opening id 7).

---

```
function show(id){
  myid = id;
  if(markers[myid]){
    map.panTo(markers[myid].getPoint());
    setTimeout('GEvent.trigger(markers[myid], "click")',500);
    map.hideControls();
  }
}
```

That's the function I used previously with one of the marker managers from v2. You have to make sure you set an id for each marker as you set it and then you can call it.

The one thing I made sure of (to simplify matters) was to make sure the map marker set/array was exactly the same as the sql result I used on the page. That way, using id's was a piece of cake.